# How to kill an android app from another app?

Tags: android, root, kill

i wanna know how to kill an android app from another, i'm developing a tasker, and i wanna to be able to kill an app selected by the user when an event occurs, i readed about Process.killProcess() but only allows me to kill apps in the same package, and that's not the idea! So, in my case, my kill section will request root rights, calling su before accept a kill request, but i don't know how to kill an app using a script! Anyones knows some script to do that??

EDIT:
The solution is in this thread:
[ANDROID: How to gain root access in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)

Please close.

Comment: This is a bad idea anyway.