# Get root from Python for Android

Tags: android, python, root, sl4a

I am using Python for Android and SL4A to write an Android app. My question is: can you get root access from Python for Android? And, if so, how?

Comment: You may want to check out [this other question and the comments/answers therein contained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own question. I ended up finding https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=184 and using the `suu` and `sush` binaries given in the answers. Worked perfectly!

**EDIT:** Timeskip update, [here's the new issue link](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a/issues/281) since SL4A moved to GitHub. Not sure how well this works with Magisk, since I personally haven't used SL4A in quite a while.