# Getting 'root" permission for Android App

Tags: android, root, android-kernel

I would like to know how can we get root permission from android app? Are there any app out there in android market?

I tried out the below line of code to list out files but nothing happened

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-", "root"});
```

I tried to give TEST_FACTORY permission in my manifest file but I got an error "permitted to system app"

How can I make my app system app?

I want help to get started with these stuff (make app if possible to get root permission) any help on this is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is a big difference between an app with root permissions and a system app.  Which one do you need?

Comment: Hm. re-reading your question, it seams as you're trying to program your own "supersu"-alternative? If so: you cannot do that in Java. You'll need C to program and compile an executable that can run natively on Android's kernel. That one can of course plug into any Java APK that handles user-interaction, but you still ned the su-executable to call your java app.

Comment: @Simaon I m basically looking to alter the Android kernel from my app. And I have no idea how to go about it. Pls help me out here. Whats the right way to get started for this purpose?

Comment: @Johannes I m basically looking to alter the Android kernel from my app. And I have no idea how to go about it. Pls help me out here. Whats the right way to get started for this purpose?

Comment: Calling shell commands using `su` is ther right way to get there. You just have to figure out what commands to call - and what commands are avialable. First thing to do: learn how to use the linux shell. Android features a bourne-shell, so you can use bourne-shell specific syntax.

Comment: @JohannesH. so can we execute shell commands using su from android app ?

Comment: Yes. see my answer on how to do that. You may also take a look at the great code linked by @NirHartmann

Comment: @JohannesH. okay so what is wrong with the code that I have posted in my question above? It was not working why is it?

Comment: It shoudl work, just do noting - su without any other command to execute won't do much. Also note that the phone has to be rooted of course, otherwise the su binary isn't available.

Comment: @JohannesH. so if I want to test the app in another device that should also be rooted right?

Comment: and also is it possible to test it out in emulator?

Comment: EVERY device that shoudl run `su`has to HAVE `su`ofr course, so yes. I don't know about the emulator, I guess it doesn't feature a su binary unless you inject one. Haven't done anything that required su myself though, so I really don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: note that you can only execute shell commands using su (= you can only use shell commands as root, not java code).

Second: Not sure if this applies to all su apps out there, but this is the help message of `su` on my phone:

```
Usage: su [options] [--] [-] [LOGIN] [--] [args...]

Options:  
  --daemon                      start the su daemon agent  
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell  
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit  
  -, -l, --login                pretend the shell to be a login shell  
  -m, -p,  
  --preserve-environment        do not change environment variables  
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default /system/bin/sh  
  -u                            display the multiuser mode and exit  
  -v, --version                 display version number and exit  
  -V                            display version code and exit,  
                                this is used almost exclusively by Superuser.apk
```

This means: you have to run `su -c something`  (or `su -c something - root`, but `root`is the default anyway). essentially this is equal to su on most Linux systems, except the daemon-thing, as there is no daemon ahndling su calls on regular linux systems.

If other su commands behave differently (which is possible), it's more secure to open a stream to a shell, execute `su`, evaluate it's return code, then proceed to execute other commands, finally execute `exit`.

Answer (score 6):

Theres a good answer here - [ANDROID: How to gain root access in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)

"As far as I know, you can only run command-line commands using root privileges. You can use this generic class I made that wraps the root access in your code: http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html"