# Unable to write to specified path in internal storage in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write to a specific path in internal storage in my android app :/data/somefolder
but I get the error java.io.filenotfoundexception : Permission denied

```
String testString="Hello World!";
    File newFile=new File("/data/somefolder/testFile.txt");
    try{
        OutputStream myOut=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile,true));
        myOut.write(testString.getBytes());
        myOut.flush();
        myOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My question is : Is it even possible to write into this folder in android internal storage or does android restrict file creation only to the specific package like 
/data/data/package/files ?

I tried using FileOutputStream and the file got created successfully in /data/data/package/files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just write into the data dir. That would require root access. You can either use the apps internal storage or the external storage (SD card). Please see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) how that works.

Comment: If you had complete root access, you would not get a Permission denied exception. Just because YOU have root access does not mean that your app has it as well, or are you sure about that?

Comment: how will i know if my app has root access?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596397/getting-root-permission-for-android-app