# How to read sysfs directories in a root android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sysfs

I need to read sysfs nodes in android directly and I have a rooted Nexus 6 (Anroid 7.1.1) phone and I need some help about possible ways of doing it.

well I can't read them directly from a user app and I got this error

```
denied { read } for name="" dev="sysfs" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app`
```

I have seen some approaches like this that copy target file to an available directory but I need more efficient ways:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cp -r /source/ /target/");
```

but what about better ways? can I grant permission to my app? or can I read them through a system app? actually my main question is that can I read them directly using Android NDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take root permission first of all to access root directory. For accessing system as root refer to this

[Getting 'root" permission for Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596397/getting-root-permission-for-android-app)