# How to access files in the data/data folder in Android, specifically for root devices, and handle "Permission denied" errors?

Tags: android, permissions, root

I've created a method to read a file in Android:

```java
@TargetApi(19)
public String getContentFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

    try {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        String everything = sb.toString();
        br.close();
        return everything;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

This code works for files in the storage folder but not for files in the data/data folder. My app is designed for rooted devices, and I'm encountering the "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" exception.

I've managed to make it work by changing the file permissions, but I'd like to know how to change permissions temporarily. Can someone guide me on how to access files in other folders and handle permission-related issues, especially on rooted devices?

Your assistance is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please log your `Exception` to LogCat, using `Log.e()`, then use the LogCat tool to examine the Java stack trace associated with your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Are you reading from your app's sub directory of data/data or someone else's? Or from the root of data/data...?

Comment: the exception is FileNotFound, but the file is present, i'm reading from root, the path example is "/data/data/somefolder/file.xml", but if i use "/storage/sdcard/somefile" this code works!

Comment: the exception say: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app only has file access to your own directory, ie /data/data/your.package.name.

EDIT: It is now evident that the OP is trying to make an app that accesses files outside of its own data directory *on a rooted device*. This makes this an entirely different question. As far as I know, it's not possible to directly make an app *run* as root. What you can do is to run `su` as a shell command, followed by whatever shell commands you need to run as root. There are several posts about how to do this, for example [ANDROID: How to gain root access in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)

This means you might have to perform all your root access operations using shell commands rather than using normal Android API:s. However, if all you need to do is access a certain file outside your own data directory, perhaps you could accomplish this by using `chown`, `chmod` etc in a rooted shell to change the permission of the file you are trying to read so that your app's UID can access it (every app is automatically assigned a unique uid such as "u0_a42"). Then you should be able to access it using normal Java file operations.

Perhaps you don't even need to actually change the owning *user* of the file to your app UID, but could use some existing *group* that your app already belongs to, such as the one controlling access to the sd card (this is speculation). You might want to give this a try:

```
su
chown root:sdcard_r /data/path/to/file
```

Provided that your app holds android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE I reckon you should now be able to access the file. You could probably even use some other group that isn't mapped to any permission.

Comment: my question is: how to access in other folders? i want make this app for root device, so it should be a way

Comment: That is not your question. Maybe you should update it to mention that very relevant fact.