# How to build Android app running on root privilege?

Tags: android, linux, root

I want to learn to build Android apps that require root permission but i find it hard to find example or tutorial on Google. So is there anyone have any good idea where can i find resources such as books, website to learn it? And one more that, i heard to build applications that run on root permission, I have to know script to communicate with kernel as android base on Linux kernel. So which script language do we use, as i found many script language out there on the internet. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANDROID: How to gain root access in an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)

Comment: @Leon, it is not the same. I want to develop application  that will work if device rooted and my app granted root permission. And if my app is not get permission, then it won't work as it it privilege to do thing. And other thing is that i want to know which script language do we use to write root app. I found some script like shell but i cannot find any tutorial to learn how to build app or learn this script as this script use to do something that we normally cannot do (But  with script and root we can write or touch even system file).

Comment: @Muhammad Babar, actually I want to build app that run on root privilege in other to do something that we normally cannot do like touch or modify system.  And sudo? As i know i ever use it in terminal before but how about build android application to touch or modify system?