# Android application user uninstalls details

Tags: android

WE have Android application in the play store, we would like to send communication to all uninstalled app users, is there any way we come to know who are the users who have uninstalled. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED is the Broadcast Auction that informs removal of application but you can't receive it on that Application which is removed. Yes if you have other application of you on same device, you can do whatever you want "Like sending that event to server" on removal of any application package!

> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed
>   from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The
>   package that is being removed does not receive this Intent.

There is an other way that give functionality of uninstall in your application and track the event. App can be uninstall this way!

```
//Uninstall event you can send to server  before start activity
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("package",
getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkUri.getPath(), 0).packageName,null));
startActivity(intent);
```

There is another way that is get root Access in your Application for that purpose this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application) may help you after becoming the SU you can do lot of things that you cant do normally!