# How to get root permissions in my app in Android

Tags: android, root, frida

In my devices, I can exec `su` in adb shell, and it show #.
but I get error by this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
FridaInjector fridaInjector = new FridaInjector.Builder(this)
                    .withArm64Injector("frida-inject")
                    .build();
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to obtain root permissions
    at com.kapplication.hook.FridaInjector$Builder.<init>(FridaInjector.java:179)
    at com.chenyee.stephenlau.floatingball.floatingBall.service.FloatingBallService.hookWhiteList(FloatingBallService.java:314)
    at com.chenyee.stephenlau.floatingball.floatingBall.service.FloatingBallService.onCreate(FloatingBallService.java:309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3588)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.kapplication.floatball.ExceptionHandler$1.run(ExceptionHandler.java:73)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6736)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I want get root access in my code.
btw, I don't have system signtrue

Comment: Have you allowed root access for apps in your root management app (e.g. Magisk app if you used Magisk for rooting)?

Comment: Try looking at [ANDROID: How to gain root access in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)

Comment: The FridaInjector library you use seems to be non-public at least Google can not find anything about it, so how should we help you if the code you present is proprietary and unknown?